# "document expired" with button submit on other action

Tags: php, html, yii

I use CHtml::button with 'submit' on other action (without form), and it shows the page, but when i click BACK and then NEXT, it shows Document Expired

```
            <?php echo CHtml::button('title', array('submit' => array('/'.$_GET['id'].'/smthing/profile'))); //)?>
```

Comment: `Document Expired` suggests that you have made a `POST` request, then attempted to navigate to the same document again using the browser's navigation buttons (back, forward). You should use the [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to avoid this.

Comment: @DaveRandom I want to use button like link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh1

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` element wrapping this button or not? Looking a the [JS source](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/framework/web/js/source/jquery.yii.js?r=1707) for what this actually does, if the button is not contained within a form element, Yii creates one with a method of `POST` and this cannot be overridden, which is frankly ridiculous. Try `echo '<form action="" method="get">'; echo CHtml::button( ... ); echo '</form>';`

Comment: @DaveRandom I don't have form element, but I have wanted to use button like link because of css style which I have for button, but I find out that it works with CHtml::link. Thank you anyway :).

Comment: You can do it by wrapping the button in a form with a GET method - see code sample in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

try changing from POST to GET, example for active form:

```
 $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action' => '/',
    'method' => 'get',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
    ),
)); 
echo Chtml::submitButton('Submit');
$this->endWidget();
```